# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'" after pipenv install

Tags: python, pipenv, pyyaml

The terminal output is shown below. I created a new folder called PrintCheckList then created a pipenv environment where I installed pyyaml.  I executed `pipenv shell` and then `python`. When I try to `import yaml` it fails.  An `ls` of the pipenv site packages reveals it's there.  I've used pipenv several times without this problem.

```
~/Python $ mkdir PrintCheckList
~/Python $ cd PrintCheckList/
~/Python/PrintCheckList $ pipenv --python 3.8 install pyyaml
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/me/Python/PrintCheckList/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (3.8.5) to create virtualenv…
⠦ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.8.5.final.0-64 in 378ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PrintCheckList-bTBe9zUr, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/me/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.2, setuptools==49.6.0, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PrintCheckList-bTBe9zUr
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing pyyaml…
Adding pyyaml to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (dc1c24)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (dc1c24)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.

~/Python/PrintCheckList $ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
~/Python/PrintCheckList $  . /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PrintCheckList-bTBe9zUr/bin/activate
(PrintCheckList) ~/Python/PrintCheckList $ pipenv graph
PyYAML==5.3.1
(PrintCheckList) ~/Python/PrintCheckList $ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  2 2020, 15:36:56) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
>>> ^D

(PrintCheckList) ~/Python/PrintCheckList $ ls ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/PrintCheckList-bTBe9zUr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
_distutils_hack           pip-20.2.2.dist-info    setuptools                    _virtualenv.py           yaml
distutils-precedence.pth  pip-20.2.2.virtualenv   setuptools-49.6.0.dist-info   wheel
easy_install.py           pkg_resources           setuptools-49.6.0.virtualenv  wheel-0.35.1.dist-info
pip                       PyYAML-5.3.1.dist-info  _virtualenv.pth               wheel-0.35.1.virtualenv
(PrintCheckList) ~/Python/PrintCheckList $
```

Comment: It's odd, I can't reproduce. Have you tried `pipenv --clear` then `uninstall pyyaml` then `install --verbose pyyaml`? Also, in the python shell, can you check `import sys; sys.path` contains that virtual env path?

Comment: sys.path does NOT contain the virtual environment path.  I checked other virtual environments and they no longer have their virtual environment path either, i.e. this is broken in all virtual environments.  pipenv is not setting PYTHONPATH.  I am running pipenv version 2020.8.13.  I have python aliased to '/usr/local/bin/python3.8' and pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8).

Comment: How did you install pipenv and what is the output of `which pipenv`?

Comment: I installed with ```sudo pip install pipenv```.  The output of ```which pipenv``` is ```/usr/local/bin/pipenv```.  To get more info I executed (but answered no to) ```sudo pip uninstall pipenv``` and it displayed
`Found existing installation: pipenv 2020.8.13

Uninstalling pipenv-2020.8.13:

Would remove:

/usr/local/bin/pipenv

/usr/local/bin/pipenv-resolver

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv-2020.8.13.dist-info/*

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/*

Proceed (y/n)? n
`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by getting rid of these aliases in my .bashrc:

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.8'
alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip3.8'
```